# PhoneGap: How do i remove Hello word screen before index.html starts

Tags: phonegap

I am new to phonegap, but I am catching on Quickly. I have built a phonegap apk online, and ran it on my phone, but before my mainpage loads, I get a phonegap blank page with a nav bar saying "hello world", unfortunately look i found no answer online to help me out. please how can i remove this ?

[image]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />

    <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: 'unsafe-inline' https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" /> -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/MBD/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/MBD/mdb.min.css">

    <title>Papyfire v.1</title>
</head>


<body style="background-color: #ffffff; ">

    <div class="row">

    <div class="card col-sm-4 mr-2">

        <h1>PhoneGap</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening gradient-purple">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </div>


    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script src="js/MBD/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
   <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/MBD/popper.min.js"></script>
   <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/MBD/bootstrap.js"></script>
   <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/MBD/mdb.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();

        setTimeout(function(){ 

            window.location="main.html"; 

            }, 3000);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The phonegap config.xml file built with the app has the default start page as index.html change your main page name to index.html.

Comment: i have customized the index page, it isn't the index page that is giving me trouble. my trouble is that i dont have any idea where the black page is coming from?

Comment: Can you tell the process how did you build the app? Is it any online builder?

Comment: Can u share some snippet of index.html page? Have you written any js code?

Comment: 1. R u getting the default output of device is ready?

2. You are redirecting to main.html check if the function is executed properly.

3. Try to comment index.js line and build the app again.

4. Well why don't you install codrova cli and build your app offline.

Comment: 1. what does "device is ready" mean ? 4. never heard of codorva cli, where do i start

Comment: @appzone_oto I meant the output of html code 
<h1>PhoneGap</h1> <div id="deviceready" class="blink"> <p class="event listening gradient-purple">Connecting to Device</p> <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p> </div>.

R u getting this when u run the app.


About Cordova CLI check this link:

https://ccoenraets.github.io/cordova-tutorial/

Comment: i am not getting that

Comment: main.html is that the page you want the use to see as the app opens up?

Comment: index.html is the page i want to see, but after the index.html loads it waits for 3 seconds and changes to main.html. index.html is my splash screen

Comment: @appzone_oto ok. 

1. Well I would suggest you to make a cordova project as it allows to set a splashscreen externally and you can also set duration for it. 

2. What's the output you are expecting for the main.html page? Because as per the code it should run index.html for 3 seconds and switch to main.html. 

3. One more thing just comment the line app.initialize(); function the index.js already call the function.

Comment: im just creating a simple music player, so i rather save mysef the stress of cordova. by the way i keey getting "cordova.js:79 Uncaught module cordova-plugin-camera.camera already defined" in my console